# Extension of diffeomorphism of convex compact subset of domains

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let ${\Omega _1}$, ${\Omega _2}$ be two domains in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f$ be a diffeomorphism between them. For every convex compact $K \subset \Omega _1$, is there a diffeomorphism $g$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $g=f$ when restricted to $K$? This is a stronger statement of [The extension of diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148808) which is proven true.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Did you analyze the 1-dimensional case? What did you conclude?

Comment: @MoisheKohan The 1d case is obviously true as $K$ is contained in a closed interval $[a, b] \in U$ which can easily be extended by linear functions using derivatives at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Nope: Why do you think that $U$ is connected?

Comment: You're right. I've added that assumption.

Comment: OK, then think about the case of an annulus $A$ in $R^2$ and $f: A\to A$.

Comment: More assumption added.

Comment: Your question appears to be a moving target. Now, think of a spherical shell in $R^3$.

Comment: Sorry. My bad for didn't think this through. There shouldn't be any obvious counterexample now.

Comment: Then it is true (at least in dimensions $\ne 4$) but non-trivial.